# Upload logo to wordpress appearance editor

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have to edit a wordpress logo in the appearance editor. The current logo SRC is set as

```
<img src="<?php echo st_get_setting("site_logo"); ?>" alt="" />
```

I have searched all of the settings but I cant find where to upload the "site_logo" to a new one. Also the editor has no buttons etc it is just source code.

Note we have version 3.5.2

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`st_get_setting("site_logo")` is particular to Smooth Themes.  Look under theme-specific settings, rather than WordPress' Settings menu.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you..

```
<h1>/"><img src="<?php echo get_option('home'); ?>/wordpress/wpcontent/themes/THEMENAME/THEME/images/YOURIMAGENAME.jpg" title="YOURTITLEORANYTEXT." alt="IMAGE TEXT." height="50" width="50" />SITE NAME TITLE</h1>
```